# Telegram URL to send message to specific bot

Tags: url, telegram, telegram-bot

Is it possible to craft a `t.me` URL that prompts the user to send a specific message to a specific bot. The closest I've found so far is `t.me/share/url?url=my%20message`, but that doesn't specify a username so the user has to choose one. I don't see the t.me URLs documented anywhere.

Note: this is not the same as sending a message via the API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use deep linking to bot, use following format like [this link](https://t.me/RawDataBot?start=YOUR_TOKEN_HERE):

```
https://t.me/username?start=<token>
```

Your backend will receive `/start <token>` .  The user however will just see normal

```
 /start
```

on their chat window.

Comment: When I try that, I just get a "Start" button that sends "/start" with nothing else.

Comment: Oh, I see... only "/start" appears, but the whole thing is sent in the webhook message.

Comment: Is any other query param than start working? Or do I have to put all in there e.g. `https://t.me/username?start=subscribe_<token>` & `https://t.me/username?start=unsubscribe_<token>`. Rather than `https://t.me/username?subscribe=<token>` & `https://t.me/username?unsubscribe=<token>`

Comment: @AndiGiga unfortunately, you can only use ?start=sub_xxx at this time :(